# Chain rule for radial and angular coordinates in higher dimension

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

I am studying the mean value property of harmonic function. In the book,

Introducing radial and angular coordinates $r=|x-y|$, $w=\frac{x-y}{r}$ and writing $u(x)=u(y+rw),$ we have 
$$
\int_{\partial B_\rho}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}ds=\int_{\partial B_\rho}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(y+\rho w)ds \cdots,
$$
where $\nu$ is outer normal vector and $ds$ indicates the $(n-1)$-dimensional area element.

It seems that the chain rule is used in the above. I don't know how to do it exactly.

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=\nabla u\cdot \nu=\nabla u \cdot w$ and what does $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(y+\rho w)$ mean exactly?

Would you give any comment for it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Definition of directional derivative : $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu } = {\rm grad}\ u\cdot \nu
$

(2) Here $\nu$ is unit out normal to $
\partial B(x_0,\rho)$ so that $$ \nu (x_0+\rho v) =
 v $$ where $|v|=1$

(3) Hence $$ \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=\rho}
 \ u(x_0 +tv ) = {\rm grad}\ u\cdot v ={\rm grad}\ u\cdot \nu  =\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu } $$